# Most efficient way to compare the values of list one with list two returning a subset of list one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of lists

```
trecords = [[1072, 'chickens', 'are', 'messy'], [1073,'chickens', 'eat', 'grass'],...]
srecords = [[1, 'chickens', 'attack', 'lizards'], [12,'chickens', 'eat', 'grass'],...]
```

I need to compare the final values of each list and returning the numerical bit of list a that is not contained in list b ... producing a list of values like `[1072,...]`

The following code works:

```
droplist = []
for trecord in trecords:
    if trecord[1::] not in [srecord[1::] for srecord in srecords]:
        droplist.append(trecord[0])
```

I would rather have something like this if it is faster:

```
droplist = [trecord[0] for trecord in trecords if trecords[1::] not in srecords[1::]]
```

But that is matching on every value and I do not know why. Actual length of the lists is 300k values each. Is this the fastest way to compare them? I've also put the data in a dictionary with the numeral being the key and the text (a list) as the value but that seems slower.

Comment: you comprehension is failing because `if trecords[1::] not in srecords[1::]` checks the last 3 values of each element in `trecords` to see if they are an independent list in `srecords`, instead what you want is to check each element in srecords and see if the last 3 values of each match

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you should use a set rather than a list datastructure for srecords, e.g. `srecords_set = {tuple(srecord[1::]) for srecord in srecords}` outside the loop, and `if tuple(trecord[1::]) not in srecords_set` inside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, I think you just needed 1 more level of nesting in your list comprehension\

```
droplist = [trecord[0] for trecord in trecords if trecord[1:] not in [srecord[1:] for srecord in srecords]]
```